# Issue converting python dataframe datatype from object to datetime

Tags: python, pandas

An example of a value in the Date column:

`19/08/2017`

Previously, I tried:

```
dividends['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dividends['Date'])
```

to convert my column to have a datetime date type. However, when I then created charts out of this dataset (with 'Date' having a datetime date type), it always looked odd:

[image]

Having done a bit of trouble shooting online, I think the reason is because of the formatting of my datetime conversion. However, when I try to use this:

```
dividends['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dividends['Date'],format='%d-%m-%y')
```

I get the error message

```
ValueError: time data '19/08/2017' does not match format '%d-%m-%y' (match)
```

Why is this, and how do I fix it? Cheers.

Comment: Change format to '%d/%m/%Y'. Does it work now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code:(note that I used `Y` in format):

`dividends['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dividends['Date'],format='%d-%m-%Y')`

You could also use the following format:

`'%d/%m/%Y'`